# Environment Variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined

Tags: windows-7, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to install Oracle 11gR2 Enterprise Edition but during database creation, I got this error :

```
Environment Variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined
```

And when I tried to launch `emctl.bat` From cmd  I got this one :

```
Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name.
```

And to solve this error, I have used this command:

```
set ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl
```

To define my Enivronment variable (orcl is the database name) I got this error :

```
EM Configuration issue. D:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/Chlebta-PC_orcl not found
```

So any help for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means you have incorrectly set up environment variables. You would have to share more details about the box, like if there are any Oracle products already installed, your Xsh profile, etc, but basically: If you are about to work with one product, you need your `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID` and also `PATH` having pointing same Oracle home. What you mention is typical when your `ORACLE_HOME` points into different home than PATH. You can avoid it by calling binaries with full path but you should fix variables anyway.

edit: A bit late I noticed Windows tag, which most probably means there is another Oracle product already installed on the same box, as Oracle on Windows uses registry for environment variables. Also, emctl is used for dbconsole/em control, not for database itself.